# Can a field ever be not-null (or its default-value) in constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a class `Foo` with a public field `MyField` (I know, bad design, was auto-generated years ago by a tool, however there are no recent plans to re-generate the code for the sake of moving towards auto-properties) and a class deriving from `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int MyField;
}
public class Bar : Foo
{

}
```

Now within `Foo`s constructor there is a check that seems suspicious to me as I assume the condition never passes:

```
if(this.MyField != 0) ...
```

The field has not been set in the base-class constructor. Thus my question is: are there any possibilites this check will ever pass?

The following cases came to my mind in order to answer that question:

1. the class `Bar` sets another default-value for `MyField`. This is only possible within `Bar`s constructor and thus will run *after* the check --> **check won´t pass**
2. constructor-chaining on `Bar`. The check itself is again executed *before* the constructor of `Bar` is executed --> **check fails again**

I hope I am not missing any case and thus can just omit that check, can´t I?

Comment: And what is actually done inside that if?

Comment: @Evk Why does this play any role? Anyway the value of the field is changed within the if-block. But I´m just interested on conditions to actually come to that point.

Comment: Is it really `Foo` constructor and not `Bar`? In latter case I'd assume what this is a check to ensure compatibility if something get changed in base class (e.g. if field gets initial value set explicitly).

Comment: @Sinatr Yeap, it´s `Foo`s constructor

Comment: Well it might be important to clarify intentions of original writer of this code. Maybe he protects from _future_ changes to this code (for example, in future you might set that field explicitly to non-zero value).

Comment: @Evk Fair enough, could imagine this based on the paranoia towards changes in our company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you don't call any virtual or abstract member from within `Foo`'s constructor *before* this check and you don't have any code in `Foo` which sets a value *before* this check, I cannot imagine how it can be anything else than 0 at this point in time.

Comment: Hmm, you´re right, I forgot about the case of a virtual member call in constructor and actually this is what happens. So I have to check if any of those overrides changes `MyField`s value. Good point

Comment: There is a code analysis warning from FxCop when a constructor calls virtual members. The reason is that code is executed from a derived class while the base class is not even initialized. This could have unexpected side effects.